# Magento 2 - Get qty from ajax response add to cart post parameters

Tags: magento2, javascript, addtocart, ajax, product-page

When click in add to cart button in view page product, with ajax response get in checkout/cart/add the qty added, i need this qty value for datalayer push in phtml, i tried getAddToCartPostParams method but not work, any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: share your code which you try, so we can help you into that one.

Comment: sorry for the delay in response, I have solved this one with .val() method for get qty value with jquery in .phtml file